# Make the simple form action a url without having a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, simple-form

Is it possible to have a simple form that purely directs to a controller action via a url and not have a model name? 
See my attempted code below, but it currently makes the url i want the form to submit to the `class` and the current url that i'm on (/appointments_table) becomes the `action` instead. So basically i want `/admin/appointments/3/delete` to be the action without the model being present.

```html
 <%= simple_form_for delete_admin_appointment_path(appointment) do |f| %>
```

```html
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form /admin/appointments/3/delete" action="/admin/appointments_table"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use symbol as the first argument for simple_form_for and also assign the url.

```
 <%= simple_form_for :appointment, url: delete_admin_appointment_path(appointment) do |f| %>
```

To get output like this

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form appointment" action="...delete/:id" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

Comment: so this isnt possible with only the url?